# magento2: unable to save text swatch attribute, "Admin is a required field in the each row"

Tags: magento2, swatches

on Magento2.2.3 unable to save text swatch attribute, getting error

```
"Admin is a required field in the each row":
```

Value is not Zero.
[image]

Only possible way to save it is to change type to dropdown or visual swatch, add value, save it and then change it back to text swatch, but i'd like to understand how to fix it, not workaround.

Comment: Not sure if this helps, but I noticed the same error message when adding an option, not filling in anything and immediately deleting it. I have a feeling that the hidden elements are also validated. I suggest, before adding / removing any option make sure the rest of the attribute is configured as you want it  to be. I mean first set the type then add / remove options. This does not solve the bug, but should work around it. (not 100% sure though.)